# How far have you understood my lesson?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, subcontinental-english

**As far as  I know  your  answer  is  correct**..I think  this  statement is  correct.

> **How  far  have  you understood  my  lesson**?

I am doubtful about  the  correctness of  the  sentence.But  how  far  means  to  what  extent. so  my  question seems  to  be  correct.

> **How  well have  you  understood my  lesson?**

I think  The  above  is  a  correct  sentence.

If  how  far  have  you  understood  my lesson  is  wrong, what  is the  correct  alternative  for  the  question   besides  how  well have  you  understood?

Here  are two  links  which  show  the  usage  of  how  far.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/how-far

https://sentencedict.com/how%20far.html

Aftet  going  through  these  two links

I have  found  this sentence:

> **How  far  has  this  penetrated into  the  general public**?

So  I  think:

> **How  far  have  you  understood  my  lesson**    is   not  at all  wrong.

Comment: After  going  through  the  links  My  question  seems  to be  correct

Comment: There are many written instances of [***so far as I understand** (the situation, blah blah)*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22so+far+as+I+understand%22), and we certainly use a similar "spatial / distance" metaphor in, say, *It's **beyond the limits** of my understanding.* But idiomatically we tend to stick with ***well*** in your cited context. Google Books has a couple of dozen instances of *"How **well** have you understood"*, but just two of *"How **far** have you understood"*. It's "okay", but not "ideal".

Comment: @ Fumble  Fingers. How far means  to  what  extent.So  my  question  is  acceptable  if  not  ideal.But  I think  it is  not  worth downvoting either

Comment: Sure - it's not worth *downvoting* (I haven't). But is it worth *asking?* Specifically, *is it worth asking **on ELU**?* You obviously *understand* the usage, and you seem to be aware that ***well*** is more idiomatic than ***far*** for the specific context, so what exactly are you looking for here? You've already got two ways of expressing the example question, and you don't seem to want anyone to tell you that one of them is "less common / more incorrect", so what *do* you want?

Answer (score 1):

Understanding is not a matter of distance but of completeness. So alternatives you could use are:

> How well have you understood my question.
>
> How completely have you understood my question.
>
> How much have you understood the information.

Note, for the last one we can't use "question" because much relates to the quantity of a substance not the completeness of it.

You could also say:

> How far have you got in understanding my question

Here you are treating the process of understanding as a journey, and you are asking how far along the journey have traveled.

Comment: orr.You  have  completely  changed  the  question.I  think  my  question  is  right  according  to  the  link

Comment: @Englishmonger *How far* has more of a connotation of *distance* traveled. So, it means something like *Until what point in time have you understood my story?*

Comment: As @FumbleFingers says, 'As far as I understand [it] ...' is totally idiomatic. You yourself give an example of the 'the process of [gaining] understanding [modelled] as a journey' metaphor. So how is 'Understanding is not a matter of distance but of completeness' really helpful? Better to say that idioms are idiosyncratic, and often need precise wording: apparently close candidate variants often don't work.